# Mongoose Methods not stored in Session?

Tags: express, mongoose

I'd like to use a Method defined in the Mongoose Model after saving the retrieved Object to a Session. Its not working though. Is it normal that these methods get lost after storing it to the session?

#### Calling Method from Mongoose Model works fine:

```
Puppies.findOne({_id:123}).then(puppy => puppy.bark()) // WOOF WOOF
```

#### Storing Model in Session and calling method fails:

```
// First Request
Puppies.findOne({_id:123}).then(puppy => {
    req.session.puppy = puppy
})

// Second Request somewhere else in the app
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.session.puppy.bark() // req.session.puppy.bark is not a function
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the exact issue, but I believe what happens is that when you're storing the variable in session, it's being toObject()'d, causing it to become a simple JavaScript object, instead of remaining as an instance of Model. I've used `Model.hydrate` as a means of recreating this Model instance.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  let puppyModel = mongoose.model("puppy");
  let puppy = puppyModel.hydrate(req.session.puppy);
  puppy.bark() // Awooo
});
```

This essentially is creating a new Model and then filling it with all the relevant information so it acts a clone.

Because it is needing all the relevant information to make an update (including _id if you have it), I believe you may need to extend the toObject function to return getters/virtuals:

```
puppySchema.set('toObject', { getters: true, virtuals: true });
```

Else, when it attempts to save, and it's missing the _id field, it won't be able to save it.

I do hope someone else can provide a nicer method of doing this and/or explain why when storing it it *has* to be converted to an object and can't remain as an instance of Model.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Ciaran Blewitt said was correct. Finally worked around it by just using [mongoose statics](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide#statics):

#### puppy.model.js

```
schema.statics.bark(puppy) {
    console.log(puppy.sound)
}
```

#### Storing Model in Session and getting desired effect via static:

```
// First Request, storing Puppy in Session
Puppy.findOne({_id:123}).then(puppy => {
   req.session.puppy = puppy
})

// Second Request somewhere else in the app
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    Puppy.bark(req.session.puppy) // WOOF WOOF
})
```